# A malware in Mozilla, An URL opens automatically?

Tags: firefox, malware, malware-removal, malware-detection, anti-malware

Some times when I open a site in Mozilla, a URL that starts with `vadabzauefrpph4xraz8ewblhsbsbxkfq7sx8d9me4nuemgnx2yt5cnyfzzlxek.com` will replace with the site's URL, What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Scan computer with `AVG` free and `Malwarebytes Anti-Malware` free edition. When you done that remove all suspiciously named extensions from Add-on window (look for "search/shopping enhance")